# How to open an existing viewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, viewcontroller

I need to open existing viewcontroller from AppDelegate while receiving push notification. Currently i am opening new one every time so issue is that it is called viewDidLoad every time and all variable are reinitialized again and again.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"Got Message"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userInfo forKey:@"message"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];            

            HomeViewController* room = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:room
                                                         animated:NO
                                                       completion:nil];



}
```

Comment: What is your root, is it a navigationcontroller?

Comment: no , no navigation controller in whole app.

Comment: no, if it is open then ok otherwise device will vibrate only.

Comment: if it is open then pass notification data to home page

Comment: I need to know what is your rootViewController? if it is not a navigationController, it must be tabarController, or it is a single view app, how you are managing you views, then only I can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"Got Message"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userInfo forKey:@"message"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];            

                [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.room
                                                             animated:NO
                                                           completion:nil];



    }

    - (UIViewController *)room {
    if (_room == NULL) {
    _room = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return _room;
    }
```

Then you can reuse your view controller (However, it will exposure the view controller in your AppDelegate, which may be a taste in clean code).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use a existing view controller, why do you use the code `HomeViewController* room = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];`?

Follow your goal, my suggestion is use a property to retain the existing view controller, just like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *existingViewController;
```

and you

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:existingViewController
                                                     animated:NO
                                                   completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get UINavigationController in AppDelegate meethod

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = //your view controller to show after push
UINavigationController *navController = self.window.rootViewController;
[navController popToViewController:yourViewController animated:YES]
```

Comment: i don't have navigation controller at all.

Comment: some where in your project Did you use bellow line?

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:compDetail animated:YES];

Comment: otherwise you should use this.
[navController presentViewController:compDetail animated:YES cmpletion:nil];